# Simple iis rewrite doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-manager

This is what I'm doing in iis manager:

iis - url rewrite -> Add rule ->

**Action type**: rewrite

**Pattern**: MySite.com (Exact match)

**Rewrite url**: MySite.com/Folder1/Default.aspx

So how do I return the `Default.aspx` page while maintaining the `MySite.com` in the address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I found the answer:

Only the part **after** the domain name and trailing slash should be entered.